# How to publish an asset within a widget in Yii2

Tags: yii2

In Yii 1 it was possible to publish an asset with:

```
Yii::app()->getAssetManager()->publish(Yii::getPathOfAlias('ext.MyWidget.assets'));
```

How can I publish an asset within a widget in Yii2?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In your view of your widget:

```
app\assets\AppAsset::register($this); // $this == the View object
```

Check [the docs](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/guide-structure-assets.html).

Comment: Hm, I have tried that, but no effect... How does the asset manager know, which assets are connected to the view?

Comment: @slaver113 because new AssetBundle has no unique name

Answer (score 3):

Simplest way of doing this:

```
app\assets\AppAsset::register($this->getView());
```

It is the same way you would publish it in a view.

Answer (score 2):

## The problem for this case in the question.

In Yii2 AssetBandle should be unique because it avoids duplication on load same files on a web page. In Yii1 it was a problem.
Almost all of the suggested answers here do not solve this problem.

That why the answer should be like this:

**You should create new asset bundle**(yii\web\AssetBundle) with a unique name that globally identifies it among all asset bundles used in an application. The unique name will be checked by [fully qualified class name](http://php.net/manual/en/language.namespaces.rules.php). After uses follow:

```
YourAsset::register($view);
```

or

```
 $view->registerAssetBundle(InterrogateDeviceButtonAsset::class);
```

Answer (score 1):

Nearly the same :

```
Yii::$app->getAssetManager()->publish('/path/to/assets'); // you can use an alias
```

http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/yii-web-assetmanager.html#publish()-detail

But if you want to publish css and js, it should be better to create an asset bundle, read more here : http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/guide-structure-assets.html#defining-asset-bundles

Answer (score -1):

I have implemented this function in my `BaseController.php` which is extended by all my controllers. It's a function to **publish a single asset**.

```
/**
 * Publish an asset and return url
 *
 * @param $src
 *
 * @return mixed
 */
public function publishAsset( $src ) {
    $path = Yii::getAlias( $src );
    if ( ! $this->assetManager ) {
        $this->assetManager = new AssetManager();
    }
    $return = $this->assetManager->publish( $path );
    return $return[1];
}
```

The only thing I'm trying to adjust is making it possible to include the full URL scheme. I've posted my question about that here [Yii2 AssetManager published path include URL scheme](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32676450/yii2-assetmanager-published-path-include-url-scheme)