# Yii2 AssetManager published path include URL scheme

Tags: yii2, assets

In my controller I have implemented a function for publishing a single asset, such as an image, and return the URL:

```
/**
 * Publish an asset and return url
 *
 * @param $src
 *
 * @return mixed
 */
public function publishAsset( $src ) {
    $path = Yii::getAlias( $src );
    if ( ! $this->assetManager ) {
        $this->assetManager = new AssetManager();
    }
    $return = $this->assetManager->publish( $path );
    return $return[1];
}
```

And then call it in my view like this:

```
<?= $this->context->publishAsset('@app/assets/img/logo.png') ?>
```

Working fine, but the function returns the published URL without the 'scheme' in front of it.
For example it returns `/assets/7cf54cf2/img/logo.png` instead of `http://www.example.com/assets/7cf54cf2/img/logo.png`

How can I use the AssetManager or adjust my code so I can get the full URL?
I can't find an answer in the documentation, the only solution I have come up with so far is adding it in front manually before returning.

I came onto this problem when trying to use this function in generating HTML for e-mails. Of course URLs in e-mails must contain the scheme in front of it.

Any suggestions other than mine? Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try  using url helper

```
use yii\helpers\Url;

$publishedPath = $this->assetManager->publish( $path );
   return (Url::to($publishedPath[1], true));
```

Comment: Pointed in the right direction, but doesn't work because `publish()` returns an array, which `Url::to();` can't handle.

Comment: I will indeed accept it since you pointed me in the right directon

Answer (score 0):

Would you mind to show your solution how you have got the absolute paths used for your linked css and js files?

My solution is:

```
\Yii::setAlias('@web', Url::base(true));
\Yii::$app->assetManager->baseUrl = Yii::getAlias('@web/assets');
```